# SwiftUI Text Field in Navigation Bar only allows one character at a time

Tags: swiftui

I have a search bar that I use within the Navigation Bar of a Navigation View, but I can only type one character into it at a time before it loses focus and I have to re tap on the text field to enter another character.

The Text Field is currently a toolbar item of the Navigation Bar:

```swift
 .toolbar{
                //The big blob of code is just to format the search bar
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal){
                    TextField("Search for Receipts", text: $searchInput, onCommit: {self.runSearch = true})
                            .padding(7)
                            .padding(.horizontal, 50)
                            .background(Color(.systemGray6))
                            .cornerRadius(8)
                            .overlay(
                                HStack {
                                    Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                        .padding(.leading, 8)
                             
                                    if isEditing {
                                        Button(action: {
                                            self.searchInput = ""
                                        }) {
                                            Image(systemName: "multiply.circle.fill")
                                                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                                .padding(.trailing, 8)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            )
                            .onTapGesture {
                                self.isEditing = true
                            }
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8.0)
                            .stroke(lineWidth: 1.0)
                            //.padding(.horizontal, 10)
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    )
                }
```

The isEditing variable is used to include a grey cancellation button that lets the user clear their input.

Does anyone know of a way to make it act like a normal text field, or the reason why this is happening?

Comment: your code works without any problems for me on macos 12.beta, xcode 13.beta, target ios 15 and macCatalyst. Maybe it gets stuck somewhere else, like the runSearch function?

Comment: I think it has something to do with placing the Text Field within the Toolbar. I placed it in NavigationBarItems and had no issues, not sure why this would make a difference though